# Javascript array while loop. Comparing results: arr[len] vs arr[len-1]

Tags: javascript, html

Good day everyone!

I've found this great code from this site:

```
var points = [30,100];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myArrayMax(points);

function myArrayMax(arr) {
    var len = arr.length;
    var max = -Infinity;
    while (len--) {
      if (arr[len] > max) {
        max = arr[len];
      }
    }
    return max;
}
```

source: [Find the min/max element of an Array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

It really works really well and very fast. I've got a question (out of curiosity). When I tried to add (or manipulate) something, the result didn't match based from the first code. Here is the code:

```
var points = [30,100];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myArrayMax(points);

function myArrayMax(arr) {
    var len = arr.length;
    var max = -Infinity;
    while (len--) {
      if (arr[len-1] > max) {
        max = arr[len-1];
      }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I've assumed that the `array[0]` is the first array element, also I used post-decrement function, and yet I didn't get the expected result.

Comment: What will happen on the last round (`len === 0`) in your modified example?

Comment: Take note that you also can use the builtin `Math.max` like this: `Math.max.apply(null, [30, 100])`

Comment: Using `Infinitie` is a generally bad practice. let's assume that first iteratebale value match our condition best `var max = arr[arr.length-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using `arr[len-1]` adds a new problem to the mix: `Index out of bounds`. This happens when the loop iterates the last element in the loop (`len == 0` after `len--`) and you end up looking for `arr[-1]` which doesn't exist. Also, you're not checking anymore for the last index in the array (`arr[arr.length - 1]`), since `len--` already substracts from the index. Like so:

```
var points = [30,100];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myArrayMax(points);

function myArrayMax(arr) {
    var len = arr.length; // len == 2
    var max = -Infinity;
    while (len--) { // len == 1
      // checking for arr[len - 1] the first time
      // results in checking for arr[0]. arr[1] will be skipped
      if (arr[len-1] > max) { 
        max = arr[len-1];
      }
    }
    return max;
}
```

The function works well in the first place, so... Why fix what isn't broken?

Check out [arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic_operators) for more info on `len--`.

Comment: Yes, but the while condition also substracts 1 from `len`'s value. Check out [arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic_operators)

Comment: Based on my observation:
When it enters in while loop, the initial value of len is 2. The condition is accepted and proceeds in if statement. When I used len-1, it should direct in arr[1]=100 not 30. When the value finished storing the value in var max, the len will be deducted and repeats the while loop. May I know why it bypasses the if (arr[1] > max) or was my understanding in using the while loop is wrong ? Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: The initial value of `len` is 2. Then the `while` condition comes and evaluates ([and operates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic_operators)) upon `len--`. Now `len`'s value is 1. Now, on the first iteration, checking for `arr[len-1]` will go to the `0` position of your array.

Comment: Saying `len--` is the same as saying `len -= 1`

Comment: I see. I thought that it is a post-decrement, not a standard arithmetic operator. Thank you very much.

Comment: It operates right after evaluating the variable. For instance: `let num = 10; console.log(num-- + num--);` will output `19`.

Comment: I see. I assumed that the len-- is a post-decrement, when in reality, it is a standard arithmetic operator. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is, but it decrements *right after* evaluating the variable. In a similar manner, `--len` decrements *right before* evaluating, such that, in the example above, `let num = 10; console.log(num-- + --num);` outputs `18`.

Comment: I see. I'm still learning to code and I'll add this to my notes. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: For further reference, you can read `len--` as 'Evaluate `len` and substract 1', and `--len` as 'Substract 1 and evaluate `len`'

Answer (score 0):

```
function myArrayMax(arr) {
var len = arr.length;
var max = -Infinity;
while (len--) { // here itself you are decrementing the value of len
  if (arr[len-1] > max) { // here also you are checking the previous one. Then you won't get chance to check the last array element.
    max = arr[len-1];
  }
}
return max;
}
```

// moreover you will get index out of bound exception while going in last iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much