# How to get the index of the min value in an array using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, min

I wrote this function, which returns `-1`.

```js
function sayHello() {
  let arrayEdificiosNiveis = [11,10,10];
  var indexMenor = arrayEdificiosNiveis.indexOf(Math.max(arrayEdificiosNiveis));
  console.log(indexMenor);
}
sayHello();
```

I expected 0, not -1. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the min/max element of an Array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: That's because `Math.max()` doesn't take a basic array argument. See:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Comment: I will have a look, ty

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to spread the array for getting the maximum. Otherwise you get `NaN` as value (via a stringed array) and this is not in the array (and not searchable).

A spreaded array takes all elements as parameter for the function ([spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)).

In this case it follows this way

```
Math.max(...[11, 10, 10])
```

is evaluated as

```
Math.max(11, 10, 10)
```

```js
function sayHello() {
  arrayEdificiosNiveis = [11, 10, 10];
  var indexMenor = arrayEdificiosNiveis.indexOf(Math.max(...arrayEdificiosNiveis));
  
  console.log(indexMenor);
}

sayHello();
```

A single loop solution:

But why not use

```
v > a[r] ? i : r
```

(which feels more natural, sort of) instead of

```
v <= a[r] ? r : i
```

The problem is the first comparison with the first element at index zero. at this time, `r = -1` and the element is `a[r] = undefined`.

A comparison with `undefined` and a relational operator of `<`, `<=`, `>` or `>=` is always `false` and that would return the wrong index of `-1` instead of zero and this result does not change for any other element of the array.

```js
const
    getFirstIndexOfMaxValue = array =>
        array.reduce((r, v, i, a) => v <= a[r] ? r : i, -1);            

console.log(getFirstIndexOfMaxValue([]));
console.log(getFirstIndexOfMaxValue([11]));
console.log(getFirstIndexOfMaxValue([11, 10]));
console.log(getFirstIndexOfMaxValue([11, 10, 10]));
console.log(getFirstIndexOfMaxValue([10, 11, 10]));
console.log(getFirstIndexOfMaxValue([10, 11, 10, 11]));
```

Comment: This is a bad answer. It needlessly searches the array twice.

Comment: @Timmmm, right, this answer was focussed on the use of `Math.max`. please have a look to the edit, where a single loop returns the index of the first found max value

Comment: Definitely better! Unfortunately if you check the link in my answer  `reduce()` is almost as slow as `max` followed by `indexOf`. Or at least it was in 2014. Probably worth benchmarking again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your approach is the complete array you're passing on the function `Math.max`:

```js
const arrayEdificiosNiveis = [11, 10, 10],
  max = Math.max(...arrayEdificiosNiveis);
  
console.log(arrayEdificiosNiveis.findIndex(elem => elem === max));
```

If it's not possible to use `Spread syntax`, you can call the function `apply` which receives an array as the parameters of function `Math.max`

```js
function sayHello() {
  const arrayEdificiosNiveis = [11, 10, 10],
    max = Math.max.apply(null, arrayEdificiosNiveis),
    indexMenor = arrayEdificiosNiveis.indexOf(max);
  console.log(indexMenor);
}
sayHello();
```

Comment: @NinaScholz you're right!.. this is a second alternative.

Comment: ... and how is this different from the answers in the proposed duplicate?

Comment: this is returning the index of the min - not the min itself - the former being what this question provides and what I need right now!

Comment: This pointlessly searches the array twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140526-00/?p=903). It turns out the obvious C-style way is the best. Perhaps unsurprisingly - C style code is easy for Javascript engines to optimise.

```
function indexOfSmallest(a) {
 var lowest = 0;
 for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i] < a[lowest]) lowest = i;
 }
 return lowest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let array=[-2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 6, 10, 8, 9]; //or [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] 
let result = "";
let fin = "";
let i = 0;
while (i <= array.length)
{
  i++;
 let temp = array[0]; //Assigning the first element of the array
  let temp1 = array[i]; //Assigning the elements through iterating the array
if (temp === temp1){ // If the value of the array is same as [1,1,1,...]
    fin = temp;
    result = temp1;
}
else if (temp > temp1){ // assign minimum value in result variable
  result = temp1;
}
else if(result < temp){ // assing minimum value in fin variable if the first element is minimum
 fin = result; 
}
}
if(fin < result){ // display the result
 console.log(fin); 
}else{            // display the result
console.log(result);
}
```