# Google Script: Function to compare string against array of strings and return value with lowest Levenshtein distance

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to write a function for use in Google Sheets that compares the string in one cell against the values in a range of other cells and returns the string with the lowest Levenshtein distance. For example:

```
  |        A         |        B
---------------------------------
1 |  Nick Cheetah      Zachary Lavalle
2 |                    Hello Kitty
3 |                    James Franco
4 |                    Nicholas Cheetah
```

The function I am trying to write in Google Sheets would have the form
`=MyFunction(A1,B1:B4)` and would return "Nicholas Cheetah"
I have the code for computing the Levenshtein distance from another sub, but where I am running into issues is storing the distance for every value in a range and then returning the value with the lowest distance.

```
function Levenshtein(a, b) {
  if(a.length == 0) return b.length; 
  if(b.length == 0) return a.length;

  // swap to save some memory O(min(a,b)) instead of O(a)
  if(a.length > b.length) {
    var tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
  }

  var row = [];
  // init the row
  for(var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++){
    row[i] = i;
  }

  // fill in the rest
  for(var i = 1; i <= b.length; i++){
    var prev = i;
    for(var j = 1; j <= a.length; j++){
      var val;
      if(b.charAt(i-1) == a.charAt(j-1)){
        val = row[j-1]; // match
      } else {
        val = Math.min(row[j-1] + 1, // substitution
                       prev + 1,     // insertion
                       row[j] + 1);  // deletion
      }
      row[j - 1] = prev;
      prev = val;
    }
    row[a.length] = prev;
  }

  return row[a.length];
```

Code so far:

```
function comp_distance(a,b) {
  a = "Nick Cheetah"
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Agent_Info"); //define spreadsheet name
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,last_row)
  var values = range.getValues();
  var new_array = new Array();
  var lev_array = new Array();

for (var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
 new_array[i] = range[i]
}

for (var i=0; i < new_array.length; i++) {
  lev_array[i] = Levenshtein(a,new_array[i])
}

Logger.log(values.length)
Logger.log(new_array)
}
```

The code is erroring out when trying to run the Levenshtein function on the values. However, I think my approach to the problem is wrong, as I will subsequently need to find the lowest distance between the values and return that in the function.

Any advice or help is appreciated!

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/levenshtein-distance-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

See code below:

```
function comp_distance() { 
  // define spreadsheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Agent_Info");
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  // get A1 value
  var string = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
  // get column B values 
  var values = sheet.getRange(1,2,last_row,1).getValues().flat();
  
  // get Levenshtein values on each element
  var lValues = values.map(value => Levenshtein(string, value));
  // get index of the minimum of lValues and pass to values array as index 
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/55677167/14606045
  Logger.log(values[lValues.indexOf(Math.min(...lValues))])
}
```

[image]