# Take object with min value in array

Tags: javascript

I'm with a small problem that can not be solved.
I need something in javascript that takes only the value closest to zero in an array.
The array is the following:

```
[{priority: 0, instance: "DNI"},
{priority: 1, instance: "CUIT"},
{priority: 2, instance: "CEDULA_IDENTIDAD"}]
```

What I need, is some function that stays only with:

```
{priority: 0, instance: "DNI"}
```

thank you!

Comment: I'm still not clear what the question is. Could you please explain more?

Comment: I would review solutions to this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: @DhavalJardosh What I need is to save the object with the value "property" closest to 0 to a variable, or to be 0

Comment: If the priority can have a negative value and you want the closest to zero object:

    `data = [{...}];
    data.reduce((p, c) => Math.abs(c.priority) - Math.abs(p.priority) < 0 ? c : p, data[0]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that priority doesn't become negative, You can do it using simple `reduce`:

```
const queue = [{ priority: 0, instance: "DNI" },
            { priority: 1, instance: "CUIT" },
            { priority: 2, instance: "CEDULA_IDENTIDAD" }];

const minObject = queue.reduce((p, c) => {
    return p.priority < c.priority ? p : c;
});
```

**ES5:**

```
var queue = [{
  priority: 0,
  instance: "DNI"
}, {
  priority: 1,
  instance: "CUIT"
}, {
  priority: 2,
  instance: "CEDULA_IDENTIDAD"
}];

var minObject = queue.reduce(function (p, c) {
  return p.priority < c.priority ? p : c;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me this but that is not ES6? I'm working on something that does not allow to develop in es6

Comment: Added Es5 version