# Best way to find lowest number in a list of objects using math.min?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Heres my code, which works but i feel like there is a more simple way doing this. The bold part is where i want to change.

```
interface properties {
    age: number;
    salary: number;
    name: string;
}
let minSalary: any;
let maxSalary: any;

let list: properties[] = [
    {name: "P", age: 12, salary: 100},
    {name: "S", age: 80, salary: 12000},
    {name: "Q", age: 25, salary: 80000},
    {name: "W", age: 55, salary: 45000},
    {name: "E", age: 32, salary: 25000},
    {name: "V", age: 5, salary: 0}
];


**minSalary =  Math.min.apply(Math, list.map( salaries => {
    return salaries.salary;** // This is the code i want to make easier
}
));

console.log(minSalary);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the min/max element of an Array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This is a shorter version:

```
const minSalary =  Math.min(...list.map(x => x.salary))
```

```js
let list = [
    {name: "P", age: 12, salary: 100},
    {name: "S", age: 80, salary: 12000},
    {name: "Q", age: 25, salary: 80000},
    {name: "W", age: 55, salary: 45000},
    {name: "E", age: 32, salary: 25000},
    {name: "V", age: 5, salary: 0}
];

const minSalary =  Math.min(...list.map(x => x.salary))

console.log(minSalary);
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min

Comment: This also needs a test for the list being empty.

Comment: depends what you expect as output. If you want the minimum price someone has to pay actually `Infinity` is not a bad result for an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce

```js
minSalary = list.reduce((least, x) => Math.min(least, x.salary), Infinity)
```

Comment: As long as the list is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `properties` as a **interface**, make it a **class**, and have a method called `toString` and return `this.salary` (though it is a number type), and then in do `Math.min(...list)` directly. You can have a method called `valueOf` instead of `toString` as well as an alternate, that will work too.

```js
class properties {
  constructor(name, age, salary) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;
  }
  toString() { return this.salary; }
}

let list = [
    new properties("P", 12, 100),
    new properties("S", 80, 12000),
    new properties("Q", 25, 80000),
    new properties("W", 55, 45000),
    new properties("E", 32, 25000),
    new properties("V", 5, 0)
];

console.log("Min: ", Math.min(...list));
```

As you are compiling it from a Typescript to JavaScript you can write this code in a more cleaner way.

Now, this will work (without overhead) incase you are constructing the data from your side. Incase you are receiving this data, then each object will not contain this `toString` method. however you can `convert` each of them to `property` class instance, but then this will not give you any additional benifit as still you have to use a `map`, and then `min`