# "TypeError: Math.min is not iterable" using spread operator

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, I'm trying to take some numbers from the user, save them in an array and then get the minimum value of the array. I used this answer to find the minimum value: [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript). My problem is that when I run my code, I get this exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Math.min is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) at voti.js:11
```

Here's my code:

```
function getNumbers() {
    var nums = prompt("Insert numbers", "");
    if (nums != null) {
        return nums.split(" ").map(Number);
    }
}

var Statistic = {
    nums : getNumbers(),
    min : Math.min( ...this.nums )
}
```

Comment: How are you calling nums and min from `Statistic`?

Comment: Inside an HTML file, in this way:
`<script>document.write(Statistic.nums) </script>`
`<script>document.write(Statistic.min)</script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` doesn't work when it's not inside a function call. You can refactor your code to store the array in a number:

```js
var nums = getNumbers();
var Statistic = {
    nums: nums,
    min: Math.min(...nums)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by wrapping the `Math.min( ...this.nums )` inside a function and returning the result

```
var Statistic = {
  nums: getNumbers(),
  min: function() {

    // `this` here refers to `Statistic` object now
    // and `this.nums` is now the array you got from `getNumbers()`
    return Math.min( ...this.nums ) 
  }
}
```

and then you can get minimum value like:

```
<script>document.write( Statistic.min() )</script>
```

```js
function getNumbers() {
  var nums = prompt("Insert numbers", "");
  if (nums != null) {
    return nums.split(" ").map(Number);
  }
}

var Statistic = {
  nums: getNumbers(),
  min: function() {
    return Math.min(...this.nums)
  }
}

Statistic.nums;
console.log(Statistic.min())
```