# What to use instead of push?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

In the code below, I use "push" to fill and empty array.  I need help to write the above code so that it comes out the same way, without using "push".  I have been challenged to this by the book, "Head First JavaScript Programming".  I have tried, but I am stumped.

```js
let scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69,
  64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44
]
var highScore = 0
var output


for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  output = `Bubbles solution # ${i} score: ${scores[i]}<br>`
  document.write(output)
  if (scores[i] > highScore) {
    highScore = scores[i]
  }
}
let bestSolutions = []
for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  if (scores[i] == highScore) {
    bestSolutions.push([i])
  }
}


document.write(`Bubbles Tests: ${scores.length}<br>`)
document.write(`Highest Bubble Score: ${highScore}<br>`)
document.write(`Solutions with highest score: #${bestSolutions[0]} and #${bestSolutions[1]}`)
```

Comment: `filter` + `map`?

Comment: Just use `bestSolutions[bestSolutions.length] = [i]` (or a counter for the same)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly you're looking to find all max values in an array of numbers. If that is the case, you can use the `reduce` and `filter` methods as an alternative to using `push`.

```
function findMaxes(arr) {
    const max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
    return arr.filter(n => n == max);
}
```

For example:

```
findMaxes([3, 5, 1, 1, 4, 5]) == [5, 5]
findMaxes([-1, -1, -1]) == [-1, -1, -1]
```

If you want to find the positions of all maxes:

```
function findAllMaxPositions(arr) {
    const max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
    return arr.map((e, index) => [e, index])
              .filter(pair => pair[0] == max)
              .map(e => e[1]);
}
```

Comment: This does not help me because what I want returned is the POSITION of the items, not the values of the items.  Do you have any ideas of how I can get the POSITION of the items?

Comment: Just updated my answer to include how to get the positions. Hope this helps!

Comment: Minor sugegstion. You do not need `array.reduce` here. Try `Math.max.apply(null, arr)`

Comment: @kingkupps I have added reference link for original post that suggested this solution in my answer. You can check it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, one approach is the following : If you want your `bestscores` array to contain the indices of the elements in `scores` that are equal to `highscore`, you can define `bestcores` as the **map** of `scores` through the function that takes a tuple `(value,index)` and return `index` if `value == highscore` otherwise `null`.

### Examples of maps

```js
const a = [2, 3, 5, 0, 6];

const b = a.map(value => value * 2); // [4, 6, 10, 0, 12];
const c = a.map((value, index) => index); //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
const d = a.map((value, index) => value + index); //[2, 4, 7, 3, 10];

const e = a.map((value,index) => value >= 3 ? index : null);
// [null, 1, 2, null, 4]. We can deal with those nulls with a filter
const f = e.filter(value => value != null) // [1,2,4]
```

### Altogether in your case

```js
const highscores = scores.map((value,index) => value == highscore ? index : null)
  .filter(value => value != null);
```

This gives you a high level approach but is a bit computationally inefficient as it actually does a double iteration over the `scores` array. A manual iteration over your array and a `push` is actually more efficient.

Comment: Actually, this does not make sense to me because what I want returned is the POSITION of the items, not the value of the items.  The above solution returns the values.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can combine map and filter. I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

- Use `Math.max.apply` to find the highest score.
- Use a loop to find all matching values and store their indexes.

```js
let scores = [ 60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44 ]
var highScore = Math.max.apply(null, scores)
var bestSolutions = scores.reduce((acc, score, index) =>
  score === highScore ? [ ...acc, index] : acc, []
);

document.write(`Bubbles Tests: ${scores.length}<br>`)
document.write(`Highest Bubble Score: ${highScore}<br>`)
document.write(`Solutions with highest score: #${bestSolutions[0]} and #${bestSolutions[1]}`)
```

---

Algo based:

- Create 2 variables, `highScore` and `bestSolutions`.
- Loop over Array.
- For every iteration, make 2 checks:
- If current `score` is greater than `highScore`

  - If yes, initialize `highScore` with current score and initialize `bestSolutions` with current index.
- If `highScore` is equal to current `score`

  - If yes, push index to current `bestSolutions`

```js
let scores = [ 60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44 ];

let highScore = 0;
let bestSolutions = [];

for(let i = 0; i< scores.length; i++) {
  if (scores[i] > highScore) {
    highScore = scores[i];
    bestSolutions = [ i ];
  } else if (scores[i] === highScore) {
    bestSolutions.push(i)
  }
}

document.write(`Bubbles Tests: ${scores.length}<br>`)
document.write(`Highest Bubble Score: ${highScore}<br>`)
document.write(`Solutions with highest score: #${bestSolutions[0]} and #${bestSolutions[1]}`)
```

#### Reference:

- [Find the min/max element of an Array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ( ) rather than [ ] in bestSolutions.push(i)

```
var bestSolutions = [];
for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] == highScore) {
        bestSolutions.push(i)
    }

}
```

Comment: The question was about the alternative to `push`. Your answer therefore does not address the question.

Answer (score 0):

A very obvious alternative would be

```
bestSolutions[bestSolutions.length] = [i];
```

Explanation: At any time, in `bestSolutions` you have exactly `bestSolutions.length` number of elements. The first has the index of 0, the second has the index of 1, ..., the last is having the index of `bestSolutions.length - 1`. Hence, the index of the n+1th element will be `bestSolutions.length`. After assigning the new value to this index, `bestSolutions.length` will equal its former value + 1.

The edge-case in the above is when `bestSolutions` is empty, in which case it does not have first or last elements, but the suggested code will work for this case as well, because in this case `bestSolutions.length` will be 0, exactly the element you want to initialize.

```js
let scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69,
  64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44
]
var highScore = 0
var output


for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  output = `Bubbles solution # ${i} score: ${scores[i]}<br>`
  document.write(output)
  if (scores[i] > highScore) {
    highScore = scores[i]
  }
}
let bestSolutions = []
for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  if (scores[i] == highScore) {
    bestSolutions[bestSolutions.length] = [i];
  }
}


document.write(`Bubbles Tests: ${scores.length}<br>`)
document.write(`Highest Bubble Score: ${highScore}<br>`)
document.write(`Solutions with highest score: #${bestSolutions[0]} and #${bestSolutions[1]}`)
```