# How to find a largest number in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
function myarray(min, max) {
  var points = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    points.push(Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 - 100 + 1) + 100));
    points.join('<br>');
    var largest = Math.max.apply(0, points);
  }
  return points
}

console.log(myarray());
```

My task is pretty simple, I want to create 10 random numbers from 1 to 1000 in an array and then print the highest one. I think I am pretty close but when I run this I get `undefined`.

How can I fix this? and what is undefined?

Comment: 1. You're printing all numbers instead of just the highest one.
2. You are calculating the largest number at each step when adding a number to the array - that's unnecessary.
3. `points.join()` does nothing since it returns a new value which is not stored anywhere.

Comment: Click https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare `points` to the largest number. Try the below snippet.

```js
function myarray(min, max) {
    var points = [];
    var largest = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {    
        points.push(Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 - 100 + 1) + 100));
        if ( points[i] > largest ) {
            var largest = points[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(points);
    console.log(largest);
}
myarray();
```

**As per OP comment.**

```js
function myarray(min, max) {
    var points = [ 521,338,761,834,561,842,177,862,173 ];
    var largest = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {    
        if ( points[i] > largest ) {
            var largest = points[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(points);
    console.log(largest);
}
myarray();
```

Comment: Is it normal that the biggest number is 6 digits? and the last 3 numbers is the largest number in the actual array

Comment: can you give an example of an array?

Comment: random numbers:  521,338,761,834,561,842,177,862,173
largest number: 108862
ooh I see, there is no comma between largest number and 10th random digit

Comment: @Bhautik ... why are there the `min`/ `max` arguments?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is move the call to `Math.max.apply(0, points)` outside the loop which is building the array and return that. Also, no need for the `points.join` line at all

```js
function myarray(min, max) {
  var points = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    points.push(Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 - 100 + 1) + 100));
  }
  var largest = Math.max.apply(null, points);
  return largest
}

console.log(myarray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1,2,3,5,25,35,43,75,100,35,3244,345,535,532]
    let maxnum = arr.reduce((pre,cur) =>{
        if(pre <= cur){
            pre = cur
        }
        return pre
    },0)
```

Comment: @Jamiec: try it with 500000 items ;)

Comment: @georg, ok for a very large set of numbers `Math.max.apply` will not work at all. But for a slightly shorter set of numbers this way is [~80% slower](https://jsbench.me/crknyc2865/1)

Comment: @Jamiec: sure, reduce is the wrong tool here, but how about a simple `for` loop?

Comment: @georg for once the OP chose the right solution (the for loop). BTW I should add the user was creating a list of just 10 numbers! It doesnt matter which solution you use with that number of items :D

Answer (score 0):

Because I love one-line solutions :)

```js
console.log(Math.max(...Array.apply(null, Array(10)).map(
      x=>Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 - 100 + 1) + 100)
    )))
```

Comment: Since you like OLS's and spread syntax why not consequently following one style ... `Math.max(...[...Array(10)].map( /*...*/ ))` then?

Answer (score 0):

**Python code**

**Brute force:**

```
arr.sort()
return arr[len(arr)-1]
```

**Optimal:**

```
import sys
largest_element = -sys.maxsize - 1 # equal to INT_MIN

for i in arr:

    if i > largest_element:
        largest_element = i
return largest_element
```

If you want understand this concept in tamil, You can checkout the below link

https://www.instagram.com/reel/C2pUF75vZBC/?igsh=M2dxMzhyMm9yeXpo

Answer (score 0):

`Math.max.call(...[some array of numbers])` will give you the largest number of the array. In your code `min` and `max` are not used at all. Here is 1/ an alternative way of creating an array (with length `len`) of numbers between `min` and `max` and 2/ the application of `Math.max`.

You may want to consider that there may be multiple largest number within the array (because the generated random values are not necessarily unique). See this [Stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sfu85y?file=index.js) if you need unique random numbers.

```js
function randomNr(min, max) {
  return Math.floor( ([...crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))].shift() / 
    (2 ** 32) ) * (max - min + 1) + min );
}

function myArray(min, max, len = 10) {
  return [...Array(len)].map(_ => randomNr(min, max) );
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  const arr = myArray(10, 50, 5);
  console.log( `${JSON.stringify(arr.sort( (a, b) => a-b))}, max: ${
    Math.max.call(...arr)}` );
}

// probable multiple maximum values (run snippet multiple times)
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  const arr = myArray(1, 5, 10);
  console.log( `${JSON.stringify(arr.sort( (a, b) => a-b))}, max: ${
    Math.max.call(...arr)}` );
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```