# Find Min and Max with javascript

Tags: javascript

Receives an integer array as argument
•

- The function transverses the array to determine the minimum and
  maximum values in the array
- Displays the calculated information as illustrated below:

functionName([-8, -1, -87, -14, -81, -74, -20, -86, -61, -10]);

// would produce following message in console:

```
The minimum value in the array is: -87, the maximum value is -1
```

Comment: `Math.min` and `Math.max`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the min/max element of an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: how i can find using one function  only ?

Comment: Call the Math.min and Math.max functions in a single function and return the two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.min` and `Math.max` return the minimum and maximum values. Since you want your function to print it out to the console, use `console.log` to print out these values, along with a templated string to have it in the format you want.

```js
const minAndMax = (arr) => console.log(`The minimum value in the array is: ${Math.min(...arr)}, the maximum value is ${Math.max(...arr)}`)

minAndMax([-8, -1, -87, -14, -81, -74, -20, -86, -61, -10]);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work.

```js
function yourFunc(arr){
 arr = arr.sort( (a,b) => a -b );
 console.info(`The minimum value in the array is: ${arr[0]}, the maximum value is ${arr[arr.length - 1]}`);
}
yourFunc([-8, -1, -87, -14, -81, -74, -20, -86, -61, -10])
```