# Javascript - lowest and highest value in array of numbers

Tags: javascript

I have an array of numbers. How do I find the highest and the lowest value in that array? What is the simplest solution?

This seems to be the simplest answer to my question:

```
var arr = [1,2,4]
var min = Math.min(...arr)
var max = Math.max(...arr)
```

It's based on [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript).

Comment: Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript seems to have the right answer to my question. I just don't know how to answer my own question...

Comment: You don't need to update the question with the answer.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: So how do I propose an answer to my question?

Comment: You don't need to. The site already recommends people to check out the other question which was previously asked.

Answer (score 0):

How about augmenting the built-in Array object to use Math.max/Math.min instead:

```
Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};

Array.prototype.min = function() {
  return Math.min.apply(null, this);
};
```

Comment: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

Comment: this question has already been answered before. please may you flag it as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

I use this function that display the max and min of an Array

```
    function arrMinMax(arr){
    const min = arr.reduce((a, b) => Math.min(a, b))
    const max = arr.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b))

    console.log("Array : ["+ arr +"]\nMin : "+min +"\nMax : " +max)
}
```

Comment: this question has already been answered before. please may you flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: this is one method, but is the long way around. Consider removing it from this (since it's a duplicate) and adding it to the duplicate solution page (if it's not already there)

Comment: Is this the simplest solution?