# Get the highest value from an Array-Javascript

Tags: arrays, loops, highest

I need to get the highest score from this Array, but it kept giving me the [0] position and the highest which is 88 and 98

```
const classInfo = {
    students: [
        { firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Smith", score: 88 },
        { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", score: 65 },
        { firstName: "Joel", lastName: "Garcia", score: 98 },
        { firstName: "Judy", lastName: "Johnson", score: 77 },
        { firstName: "Anne", lastName: "Dew", score: 88 },
          ]
        };
       let best_result //edited
       for (let i = 0; i < classInfo.students.length; i++) {
       if (classInfo.students[i].score > best_result) {
       best_result = classInfo.students[i].score; 
            console.log(best_result);
}
```

Comment: what is initial value of best_result?

Comment: Oh sorry I left that out, should let best_result = 0 and omit the second let at the end.

Comment: yes, if you are beginner then check this to learn JavaScript https://www.freecodecamp.org/

Answer (score 0):

You should define `best_result` variable outside of the loop, because if you define a variable inside a loop then for each iteration variable would get reinitialised.

```js
const classInfo = {
    students: [
        { firstName: "Joe", lastName: "Smith", score: 88 },
        { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", score: 65 },
        { firstName: "Joel", lastName: "Garcia", score: 98 },
        { firstName: "Judy", lastName: "Johnson", score: 77 },
        { firstName: "Anne", lastName: "Dew", score: 88 },
          ]
        };
       let best_result = 0;
       for (let i = 0; i < classInfo.students.length; i++) {
       if (classInfo.students[i].score > best_result) {
         best_result = classInfo.students[i].score; 
     }
}
console.log(best_result);
```

Comment: Thanks, actually in my code I had it as "edited" up there. Which looks exactly like yours. But it still came back with more than 1 highest.

Comment: it is because console log was inside the loop, now check it , console.log is outside now you'll get only one log

Comment: if this answer your question then accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most efficient way, but you can set an array of scores and get the max value :)

```js
const classInfo = {
  students: [{
      firstName: "Joe",
      lastName: "Smith",
      score: 88
    },
    {
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe",
      score: 65
    },
    {
      firstName: "Joel",
      lastName: "Garcia",
      score: 98
    },
    {
      firstName: "Judy",
      lastName: "Johnson",
      score: 77
    },
    {
      firstName: "Anne",
      lastName: "Dew",
      score: 88
    },
  ]
};

let scores = [];
classInfo.students.map((student) => scores.push(student.score));
console.log(scores);
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, scores)); // credits : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1669222/4698373
```