# Using forEach to find the minimum number

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, numbers, minimum

How do I find the lowest number in array using the forEach function in javascript?

Here is an example:

```
let arr = [10, 122, 673, 37, 85, 119, 10];
```

How would I use forEach to find the minimum number (in this case 10) in `arr`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the min/max element of an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [10, 122, 673, 37, 85, 119, 10];
let min=arr[0]
arr.forEach(item=>{if(item <min) min=item})
console.log(min)
```