# How to get max and min value from Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

i had seen lots of another examples like

`Math.max(...Array1)` or `Math.max(null,num)`  or `Math.max.apply(null,num)`

but it's not working by my code

my data size is 255 and This is what the data looks like when i print it by console.log

```
0: 55.47999954223633
1: 56.040000915527344
2: 57.52000045776367
3: 57.119998931884766
...
```

Data was extracted from the json file and then put into the array through push.
code is look like this

```
let Array =[]
jQuery.getJSON( "price.json",function(data){
        for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
             Array.push(data[i].price)
        }    
let maximum = Math.max(...Array) // not working
```

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: It does work, trying putting `Math.max(...[55.47999954223633, 56.040000915527344, 57.52000045776367, 57.119998931884766])` in your console. Check your data is what you expect it to be. Also don't call something `Array`, that's a reserved word and not a good name anyway, `prices` would be better

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the min/max element of an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669190/find-the-min-max-element-of-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: @ace1234 i tried that one before, but it's not working

Comment: @Dominic not like Math.max(...array)?

Comment: Math.max(...array) is correct, I am just creating an array inside the parentheses i.e. `Math.max(...[1, 6, 3])`

Comment: @Dominic as i  tried it works fine with that short data but as i said, it's not working with my data, i mean array size 255  (length:255 array)

Comment: @J.K plz upload `price.json` somewhere, it should work with a larger array too

Comment: Your array might have too many elements for jamming them all into Math.max at once.  See the reduce example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Comment: What's the actual error? Or output if there is no error. It's not very clear what "not working" means.

Comment: @LawrenceWebDev there is no error just result with infinity

Comment: @Dominic just a second as i check my data i mean after put data in array,  and check the length, it print out 0 any reason?

Comment: @J.K depends what is in `prices.json`, I imagine it's an object with an array in it or something

Comment: @Dominic exactly. like example: products number, price etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.max(...[])` is ES6 syntax. Maybe you are using an older JavaScript engine? Here are two versions using your data as input, one for newer ES6, one for older ES5:

```js
const dataFromJson = [
  { name: "A", price: 55.47999954223633 },
  { name: "A", price: 56.040000915527344 },
  { name: "A", price: 57.52000045776367 },
  { name: "A", price: 57.119998931884766 }
];

// ES6:
let arr1 = dataFromJson.map(obj => obj.price);
let max1 = Math.max(...arr1);
console.log('ES6 max: ' + max1);

// ES5:
let arr2 = dataFromJson.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.price;
});
let max2 = Math.max.apply(null, arr2);
console.log('ES5 max: ' + max2);
```

Output:

```
ES6 max: 57.52000045776367
ES5 max: 57.52000045776367
```

Comment: actually when i use Math.max.apply or that similar one , it print out with  :- Infinity

Comment: You get infinity if the first parameter to `Math.max.apply` is the array, hence `Math.max.apply(null, array)`. See docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: as i tried that Math.max.apply(null, array) , it also return infinity

Comment: Try `Math.max.apply(null, [1, 3, 2])` to test

Comment: seems like my array is wrong i mean after trying to push data and check the length, it said 0 idk why and what u suggest  Math.max.apply(null,[1,3,2] is  work fine

Comment: Yup, do a console print of the data you get to find out.

Comment: can i ask u something? as i get data from jQuery.getJSON and push in array, and after end of jQuery.getJSON , i can't get data from that array, do u know why it is?

Comment: This is a new question. Best to open a new question, and specify input and expected output.